# Summarise dataframe to obtain diff (lagged difference)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that I want to group and obtain the median of the diff (lagged difference) in consistent units. Is very similar to the example below. As you can see by running the code below I have problems because diff have an units attribute that is not taken into account by my `summarise` function

```
library(tidyverse)

# Initialise random data
t = Sys.time()
rnd <- sample(1:10000,10,replace=F)
add <- rnd[order(rnd)]

# Create 2 dtaaframes
time1 <- data.frame(datetime = t + add)
time2 <- data.frame(datetime = t + add * 1000)

# Bind dataframe together
mydata <- bind_rows(time1, time2, .id = "group")

# Trying to get a summary table
mydata %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(elapsed = median(diff(datetime[order(datetime)])))

# These are the values that I should get in my summary table
median(diff(time1$datetime))
median(diff(time2$datetime))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `difftime` and setting the units?

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(elapsed = median(difftime(datetime, lag(datetime), units = "mins"), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option, which will show all results in seconds. Use `dminutes(1)` or `dhours(1)` or `ddays(1)` if more appropriate.

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(elapsed = median(diff(datetime[order(datetime)])) / lubridate::dseconds(1))
```